# Android NDK:execv("/system/bin/pm", args) fail.errno is 8

Tags: android, android-ndk

I write a native executable program, in which i call execv("/system/bin/pm", args), the args is {"pm", "list", "packages", NULL}.It failed with errno 8.But execv("/system/bin/getprop", args) will succeed.exec pm in adb shell will succeed too.

Comment: Use `strerror` to figure out what errno 8 is? Check logcat?

Answer (score -1):

I take it for granted.pm is not an exectuable program.It's a script.The code below works.
char *args = {"sh", "/system/bin/pm", NULL};
execv("/system/bin/sh", args);